# Making a Bash script to set desktop wallpaper as animated gif -- what do these errors mean?

Tags: bash, scripts, desktop-background

I was following [this tutorial](https://sathisharthars.wordpress.com/2014/01/04/setting-a-animated-gif-file-as-a-desktop-background-in-ubuntu/) to see if I could make my desktop wallpaper in Ubuntu into an animated gif. In the tutorial, I copy and pasted a script that would supposedly allow me to do this. Everything is okay up until I try to run the script.

This is the script:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    # Uses xwinwrap to display given animated .gif in the center of the screen

    chmod +x gifbg.sh

    if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo 1>&2 Usage: $0 image.gif
    exit 1
    fi

   #get screen resolution
   SCRH=`xrandr | awk '/current/ { print $8 }'`
   SCRW=`xrandr | awk '/current/ { print $10 }'`
   SCRW=${SCRW%\,}

   #get gif resolution
   IMGHW=`gifsicle --info $1 | awk '/logical/ { print $3 }'`
   IMGH=${IMGHW%x*}
   IMGW=${IMGHW#*x}

   #calculate position
   POSH=$((($SCRH/2)-($IMGH/2)))
   POSW=$((($SCRW/2)-($IMGW/2)))

   xwinwrap -g ${IMGHW}+${POSH}+${POSW} -ov -ni -s -nf — gifview -w WID $1 -a

   exit 0

   :wq
```

When I try to run the script in the terminal, it returns the following:

```
    gifbg.sh: 23: gifbg.sh: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "(1366/2)-(/2)"
```

When I run gifsicle with the specified image in the terminal, it returns the following:

```
    * /home/bc/Pictures/tvStatic.gif 4 images
    logical screen 500x375
    global color table [256]
    background 0
    loop forever
    + image #0 500x375
    disposal previous delay 0.08s
    + image #1 500x375
    local color table [256]
    disposal previous delay 0.08s
    + image #2 500x375
    local color table [256]
    disposal previous delay 0.08s
    + image #3 500x375
    local color table [256]
    disposal previous delay 0.08s
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21839/discussion-on-question-by-brandon-copeland-making-a-bash-script-to-set-desktop-w).

Answer (score 0):

The first three errors are because you have non-ASCII `‘` (and `’`) characters in your script - you need to replace them with regular single quotes `'`

The fourth is likely because your shebang `#!/bin/sh` is invoking the `dash` interpreter, not `bash`: see [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)

Comment: Dash has no problems with arithmetic using `$(( ))` - I think it's because of an empty variable, since the `awk` commands didn't execute correctly.

Comment: Fixed the problems you mentioned. It's yielding a slightly new error, but it's very similar to the last one:  

gifbg.sh: 22: gifbg.sh: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "(1366/2)-(/2)"
By the way, I kept the sh part of the shebang. When I replaced it with Bash, it returned a whole other mess of issues.

Comment: @muru I think you were right about the empty variable. Once I got the awk to execute it was filled with "1366." But as you can see in my reply, it's still saying it's expecting a primary.

Comment: @BrandonCopeland one of your variables is still empty. Note the `(/2)` - there's nothing before the `/`.

Comment: @muru I'm not sure why. the terminal didn't return anything about the awk commands this time.